# Button text vertical alignment is off in Android

Tags: java, android, button

I'm having trouble with button text alignment in my Android app.  I have a button defined in XML like this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/reportanissuebutton"
        android:layout_width="272sp"
        android:layout_height="32sp"
        android:text="@string/button_report_issue"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@xml/report_issue_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40sp"/>
```

The result is this:

[button.jpg](http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/5729/buttonsz.jpg)

I was expecting the text to be centered both vertically and horizontally as it does with all of the other buttons in my application, but for some reason with this one it is offset slightly down.  I can't seem to figure out why its doing this, so any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Here is the XML for the background of the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
    <stroke android:color="#c2c2c2" android:width="2dp" />
    <gradient 
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#000"
        android:endColor="#919191"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: the text is already centered... what else do you want to change?

Comment: it's not centered vertically, there is more space on top than on bottom.

Comment: have you tried either removing gravity tag at all or using only vertical?

Comment: i guess you can try to set padding

Comment: @Rosalie: I set `android:paddingBottom="3sp"` and that seems to get it lined up correctly.  I'm still curious to find out why this is the only button in the entire app that can't align the text automatically, though.

Comment: actually i don't know the exact reason why it happens sumtyms but a small suggestion i have seen your xml file in which you specified every attribute value in "sp" beter to use "dip" or "dp" for widths, heights etc. and "sp" should be used only for text size then the desig will be proper.

Comment: then perhaps it is "centered" and if you'd like a different appearance - use padding

Comment: @Rosalie: Tried that, didn't seem to have any effect.  I'm just going to leave the padding in there and move on.

Comment: ok try in whichever way you feel better

Comment: A downvote without an explanation is not very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: dip will size on different devices much better than sp and declaring  no gravity  is by default completely centered

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/reportanissuebutton"
    android:layout_width="272dip"
    android:layout_height="32dip"
    android:text="@string/button_report_issue"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:background="@xml/report_issue_button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40sp"/>
```

Additionally: This exact thing happened to me when the font was too tall for the button try decreasing the size of the font slightly and/or increasing the height of the button.... this solved my issue.

Answer (score 49):

Try this:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

It helped me with a similar problem.

Comment: This, along with setting paddingTop and paddingBottom to 0dp helped.

Comment: Finally some clever guy tells right answer instead of of things every android developer already knows !

Answer (score 8):

If you are building your view programmatically, use this:

```
button.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

That worked for me:

```
android:gravity="fill_vertical"
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

S really complete answer is this..

```
   <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
   <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
   <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
```

..in some cases when desired button height is too small compared to font size.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the vertical text alignment.
Turned out, it happened because of increased vertical line spacing (at the button's parent style) by setting `android:lineSpacingExtra`.
So make sure you do not have it specified or set `android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"` (in case you have to override parent style).

Answer (score 0):

Im Use this:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:minWidth="1dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="O\nP\nC\nO\nN\nE\nS"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

I just add a line break

Answer (score -2):

use

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

It will definitely fix your issue.

If you find this useful then dont forget to mark it as an answer.

Best Regards,

~ Anup

Comment: Nope, this is what it looks like now:
[link](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/382/button2h.jpg)

I'll also add the XML I'm using for the background of the button to the original question.

Comment: not sure I understand your question, the image I posted in the comment above shows the result from replacing `android:layout_height="32sp"` with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`